# Is there design patterns I can use to implement an RPC (client-server) in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, rpc

I'm working on a personal project which is an RPC (client-server) in C++.  The RPC will communicate over TCP/IP or HTTP. The spec of the RPC is here :

http://groups.google.com/group/json-rpc/web/json-rpc-2-0

I'm wondering if there is an existing design pattern (or a combination of pattern) that could help me to produce a clean and flexible design. I will appreciate to have code examples, UML diagrams, or articles.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the point of this?  You are using the wrong serialization format (not Soap) and the wrong runtime environment (no reflection).  The horsepower of C++ just doesn't matter when you've got milliseconds of network latency.

Comment: 1) Wrong serialization : Because I like more JSON syntax than XML (less verbose) 2) Wrong runtime (no reflection) : I will use Qt (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/metaobjects.html)

Comment: >> What is the point of this? As I wrote : I do it for a personal project. So, the main point of it is to learn something new (Networking, RPC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably going to need a [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) on the client to represent and make callable locally any server-side methods that you will be calling.

Under the covers, [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) could be useful to encapsulate provision of a concrete network connection that is selected using a configured or requested protocol (TCP, HTTP).

Answer (score 0):

I would go for Observer.

[Details and diagrams.](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you asking in regards to high level design (observer patterns, JSON/XML processing techniques, etc.), low level design (sockets, HTTP client/server handling, etc.), or both.

If interested in lower level aspects including scalability, it might be worthwhile to study the design and motivations behind ASIO: http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.3.1/doc/asio/overview.html .

Comment: It's more high level.  I will re-use an existing library for JSON processing.